# Multi- Objective optimization: how to prove :An optimal solution of the max-ordering problem is weakly efficient but not necessarily efficient.

Tags: optimization

For multi-objective optimization problem. A method to find weakly efficient is using max-ordering, which is $min_{x\in X}\  max_{i=1,...n}f_i(x)$.

How to prove that:An optimal solution $x^o$ of the max-ordering problem $min_{x\in X}\  max_{i=1,...n}f_i(x)$ is weakly efficient.

I have try to prove by contradiction. Firstly suppose that there is a point $x^c$ that $f_j(x^c) < f_j(x^o)$ . When the $f_j(x^c) = max_{i=1,...n}f_i(x)$. It is contradict with the suppose.

However, when the $f_j(x^c) \neq max_{i=1,...n}f_i(x)$ . There is seems not contradiction.

Where is the problem of my proof?

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you have tried, where you got stuck, and what your specific questions are. This feels a bit like you are asking us to solve a homework problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice very much. I have updated my question. Can I have your  further advice?  Thank you.

Comment: I would try coming up with a counterexample, i.e., a specific instance of the optimization problem, with actual numbers, and show that $x^o$ is weakly efficient but not efficient.